# how do I prevent numbers from going to Scientific Notations in my TextView?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

I am making a calculator. When I add too many characters, the display automatically gets this scientific notation.

How do I prevent this?

```
    if ((answer == null)) {
        answer = 0.0
    } else {
        answer = (answer * 10) + digit
    }
    answerEditText.setText(checkLast2Digits(answer.toDouble().toString()))
}

// removes the .0 from the end of the string
private fun checkLast2Digits(answerText: String): String {
    val checkLast2Digits = answerText.takeLast(2)
    if (checkLast2Digits.equals(".0")) {
        return answerText.toString().take(answerText.toString().length - 2)
    } else {
        return answerText.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using `double` here, a format which doesn't lend itself very well to calculator: limited precision and rounding errors are two reasons why. You should be using an arbitrary precision type, like `BigDecimal` like @Tenfour04 suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.toBigDecimal().toPlainString()` to avoid the scientific notation. This also removes the trailing zeros after the decimal place, so you don't need that other function either.

```
answerEditText.setText(answer.toBigDecimal().toPlainString())
```